# How to set content-type in AFnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, content-type

I'm having problem with AFNetworking. I can't set `content-type` to `application/json`. How can i do? i try a lot of solution, but no one has worked. here your are my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
  if (self.enableBasicAuth){
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:[[SOWMerchant merchant]     username] password:[[SOWMerchant merchant] password]];
  }
  [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
  [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url] parameters:postData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self onSuccessResponse:responseObject request:operation];
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self onError:error request:operation];
  }];
```

I get this response

```
{ URL: https://sbengtest.spotonway.com:9099/v1.0/merchant/check }, response: <NSHTTPURLResponse:  0x10aa20530> { URL: https://sbengtest.spotonway.com:9099/v1.0/merchant/check } { status code: 400,     headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 192;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Sun, 20 Jul 2014 22:34:59 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.2.1";
} }>
```

UPDATE:

i trye to add this

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

operationManagerInstance.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
```

my app crash

UPDATE 2:
it works. i removed this line

```
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Comment: Did you try using `AFJSONRequestSerializer` it should automatically set proper content type?

Comment: Please post response body and all request headers you're sending. Maybe there's a problem with accept header not content-type.

Comment: how can i get it? however if i make request fro postman without sepcify content-type (it take text/html as default) i get status code 400 bad request  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>

Comment: if i can't set conent-type, do you know another way to do http request and handle status code and error??

Comment: I have this exact same problem and can't figure it out.  In Postman the response comes back just fine.  In the app, an application/json is interpreted as text/plain

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and have NO IDEA what the problem is.

Comment: Better way is implementing framework own, 3rd parties will fail most cases like this. i.e., I did not able to see HTML output(error or content) by using this library.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me!

```
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Answer (score 7):

This Code Work

objective-c

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

swift

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=NSSet (object: "text/html") as Set<NSObject>
```